# Difference in authentication of WCF Channel Factory vs Service Reference

Tags: c#, wcf

I am consuming a 3rd party https web service in a WCF service using the 2 ways described below.

1. Using Service Reference

   ```
   ServiceClient client=new ServiceClient();
   client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName ="xxx";
   client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "pwd";
   ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain,                       sslPolicyErrors) => true;
   ServiceResponse response=client.GetData();
   ```

2.Using channel factory

```
  ChannelFactory<IService> client = new ChannelFactory<IService>(binding, address);
  var proxy = client.CreateChannel();
  client.Credentials.UserName.UserName ="xxx";
  client.Credentials.UserName.Password ="pwd";
  ServiceResponse response=client.GetData();
```

I am able to pass the security credentials using the first approach and i am able to get the respone back from the 3rd party web service.But I am unable to get the response when i use the second approach. I can see that the username,password are added in the security header of the outoing SOAP message with the first approach but not with the second approach.I would be glad if some one can throw some suggestion here about the channel factory approach.

Comment: A difference in bindings between these two perhaps?

Comment: I am using WSHttpBinding for both the approaches.

Comment: Did you checked the parameters of the binding regarding security?

Comment: Yeah I checked the parameters of the binding.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is when you're assigning the credentials - in your current code, you're creating the proxy after you create the factory, and *then* you assign the credentials to the factory.  But that has no effect on the created channel:

```
ChannelFactory<IService> client = new ChannelFactory<IService>(binding, address);
var proxy = client.CreateChannel();

client.Credentials.UserName.UserName ="xxx";
client.Credentials.UserName.Password ="pwd";
```

`var proxy` is a an implementation of `IChannel` - setting the credentials on the factory (`client`) has no effect on the already created channels - just the ones created later.

Try setting the credentials and *then* calling `CreateChannel()`:

```
ChannelFactory<IService> client = new ChannelFactory<IService>(binding, address);
client.Credentials.UserName.UserName ="xxx";
client.Credentials.UserName.Password ="pwd";

var proxy = client.CreateChannel();
ServiceResponse response=client.GetData();
```